# What is the adverbial phrase "after my workout" modifying in the sentence, "I am hungry after my workout."?

Tags: phrases, adverbs

I'm trying to determine if the adverbial phrase modifies the adjective "hungry" or the verb "am." Would it the answer change if the sentence were phrased like this instead: "After my workout, I am hungry."?

Comment: It modifies the whole clause _I am hungry_. Most adverbial expressions referring to time, place, or circumstance modify whole clauses or phrases. If you've been taught that there has to be some individual word that it modifies, you've been taught wrong. Most adverbial phrases can and do modify other constituents, not just individual words. And the verb _am_ is just a filler, it doesn't do anything but hold the present tense and agree with the subject. The real predicate is _hungry_, which is a predicate adjective and therefore requires an auxiliary, meaningless, _be_.

Comment: _Be_ is the only verb in the sentence, and it's carrying the tense, so it hasta be the main verb. It's not the predicate, though; that's _hungry_. "Main verb" is a phrase from grammar school, where mostly simple sentences are analyzed, and auxiliaries are distinguished from main verbs. But they never talk about predicate adjectives or nouns (except for the names); they're the real predicates, and many if not most clauses use them and not "main verbs" (= last verb in chain + predicate). That's also why folks argue about whether _tired_ is a verb or an adjective. It's both, of course.

Comment: Yes. I'm saying _be_ is **always** an auxiliary. I'm also saying "main verb" is not well-defined. If a clause has a predicate that's a verb, it's the main verb. But if a clause has a predicate that isn't a verb, "main verb" is at best a misnomer. It's not a contrast. There are several jobs: mark tense if not a modal, follow each auxiliary in a chain with an appropriate form, and display the predicate at the end. If the predicate's not a verb, it can't do the tense, so it requires an auxiliary verb to do it, and whatever subject agreement there is. Not every clause has a "main verb".

Comment: The remaining question is: why are you asking what the adverbial phrase is modifying? If your teacher has asked you to diagram the sentence, then do what your teacher tells you. If you have some other question about the structure, syntax, or meaning, ask it.

Comment: I'm the teacher and I diagrammed the "after my workout" under "am." Another teacher asked me why it didn't go under "hungry." My best response is that it answers a question about when the linking verb "is" happened. But she wondered if it could also modify the predicate adjective, "hungry." Trying to nail down a rule that would distinguish between the two.

Comment: ‎Reed-Kellogg sentence diagrams are not helpful for complex sentences; they make too many incorrect assumptions and don't have facilities to distinguish many constructions. One of the incorrect assumptions is that everything modifies one word, instead of modifying a whole constituent. @Lambie -- _I have gone_ and _I am going_ both have auxiliary verbs without infinitives.

Comment: @Lambie - I'm sorry, I'm just repeating what every linguist who's encountered R-K diagrams knows. They're based on a Latinate grammar model in which each constituent (and R-K is quite good at distinguishing constituents inside a clause) has to "modify" (which in Latin meant "agree with") one specific word. That's not the way English grammar works, unfortunately. We don't do adjective-noun agreement in number, gender, and case, for instance; English has no NP agreement at all. As far as "real predicate" is concerned, it's the thing (official Verb or not) that is being predicated of the subject.

Comment: @Lambie - maybe I should mention that "predicate" is a logical term. The logical formulas `WALK (Bill)`, `TIRED (Bill)`, and `DOCTOR (Bill)` have their predicates in capital letters. It turns out that _walk_ is a verb, _tired_ an adjective, and _doctor_ a noun. They correspond to _Bill walked_ (tense is irrelevant in logic), _Bill is tired_ (predicate adjectives require aux _be_ in English), and _Bill is a doctor_ (singular countable predicate nouns require an article as well as an aux _be_). This is elaborated in the [Logic Study Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: _Be_ in _I am hungry_ is an auxiliary because (a) it has no meaning (most real verbs do) (b) it's required by the predicate adjective ( *_I hungry_). That's what auxiliaries do. They mark and identify constructions they introduce, and they carry the tense marker, Verbs can do this already; adjectives and nouns can't. So we provide _be_ to carry it. That's all. Very simple stuff, actually. Yes, it's a verb because it conjugates; yes, it's an auxiliary verb because above. It's an auxiliary verb, like an auxiliary bishop - powers but not authority.

Comment: That's the way they do it in Spanish. We say we _have_ a party, a wedding, a baby, or the grippe. Spanish _tener_ 'have' is, like English _have_, about halfway to auxiliary status. English lost most of its inflections and is losing the rest, leaving only prepositions, conjunctions, auxiliaries, particles, and other small words to do syntax, since the morphology's effectively dead. Spanish still has morphology, but it's developing syntax, too. _Be_ plus adjective describes a state or condition because the adjective describes it. _Be_ describes nothing, any more than _of_ or _a_ or _not_.

Answer (score 1):

"After my workout" is an adverbial adjunct to (i.e. modifies) the verb phrase "am hungrey".

[image]

NB:  In a Reed-Kellogg diagram, I would put it under "am".

Comment: So am is not an auxiliary?

Comment: Syntactically, "be" is an auxiliary verb; that is, it can take a verb phrase with a main verb as a complement.  Even when it takes a noun or adjective as a complement (as in "I am hungry", where it has traditionally been called a main verb, equating it with "I feel hungry"), it is an auxiliary verb.  Continued ...

Comment: "be" is an auxiliary verb; that is, it can take a verb phrase with a main verb as a complement" So, am doing, am seeing, am going are main verb complements??